# App Elements are displayed way off in Appium Inspector

Tags: ios, macos, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am having issues with an IOS app we are using with Appium. The elements appear on the wrong part of the UI. See Image.

[image: Elements Appearing Wrong]

Anybody run into this issue? Maybe we need to build the app differently? I ran a test script, and the elements receive proper taps and interactions. It's just in Inspector they show off.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question for the Appium people?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to change in the development of an app. This is just the inspector problem. If you try and use "UI automator" everything works fine.

Comment: How do i fix the inspector problem? Do you mean UI Automation the built in Apple automation tool?

Comment: Oh i am sorry, i didn't recognize you are using iOS not android.